# Np.fromfunction работает странным образом

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

Я заметил, что функция np.fromfunction() работает странным образом. Если использовать одно выражение для каждого элемента, все работает:

```
print(np.fromfunction(lambda x, y: x * 5 + y, (3, 5), dtype=np.int_))
```

Вывод:

```
[[ 0  1  2  3  4]
 [ 5  6  7  8  9]
 [10 11 12 13 14]]
```

Но если попытаться использовать булевые переменные или ветвления:

```
print(np.fromfunction(lambda x, y: x * 5 + y if x % 2 else x * 5 - y, (3, 5), dtype=np.int_))
```

Ему это не нравится и он выдает ошибку ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all().

Можно ли как то все-таки использовать тернарные выражения в этой функции? Есть какие-то альтернативы?

Comment: А вы уверены, что и в первом варианте функция дает нужный вам результат?

Comment: я для примера, я просто хочу понять почему в данной функции нельзя использовать тернарные выражения, и как можно все таки поместить туда тернарное выражение, если вообще можно

Comment: Скорее всего потому, что метод fromfunction работает не так, как кажется. (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18702105/parameters-to-numpys-fromfunction)

Comment: то есть оно не как итератор работает, а сразу берет и делает все n ячеек на значения одного и того же выражения, да?

Comment: Да, в функцию отправляются ndarray. можете сами протестировать def f(*args):
    print(args) а затем print(np.fromfunction(lambda x, y: f(x,y), (3, 5), dtype=np.int_))